# Eliminate Clustered Index Scan in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have this query involving 2 tables joined.

```
Select  q.id, 
                         q.LastUpdatedTicksSinceEpoch,
                            q.[Type] [QuoteType],
       q.LatestFormData [FormDataJson], 
                            q.QuoteNumber, 
                            q.QuoteState,
       q.policyId,
                            p.CustomerId, 
                            p.CustomerFullName, 
                            p.CustomerAlternativeEmail,
                            p.CustomerHomePhone,
                            p.CustomerMobilePhone,
                            p.CustomerWorkPhone,
                            p.CustomerPreferredName,
       p.ProductId
                            from Quotes q
                    INNER JOIN  PolicyReadModels p on q.PolicyId=p.id
                    where
                            p.TenantId = @TenantId
                            and p.Environment = @Environment
                           and q.LastUpdatedTicksSinceEpoch > @LastUpdatedTicksSinceEpoch
         and q.QuoteState <> 'Nascent'
                            and q.QuoteNumber is not null
                            and q.IsDiscarded = 0
     ORDER BY q.LastUpdatedTicksSinceEpoch
```

When I run it and get the execution plan, I see Clustered Index Scan - which I want to Eliminate and use an Index Seek.

How can I eliminate the clustered index scan here? How can I construct a new INDEX? To add more context to this, this will query will be called by 12 parallel thread(12 connections), so I need this fast and optimized.

Here is my Query and execution plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkWjdvKDD

Comment: To be useful to other members, you should include your reasoning why you think this query can be optimised and what you have tried that has not worked, for instance what indexes have you implemented?

Comment: For the Quotes Table, only the PK. I will have this query run in parallel threads (12 connections).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

- Filters by your two fixed values (QuoteNumber NOT NULL and IsDiscarded = 0)
- Sorts the data by LastUpdatedTicksSinceEpoch (as you are passing a variable to that in your WHERE clause, and it appears the most likely one you want to sort on
- Includes all other relevant fields so doesn't need to go back to the clustered index (e.g., becomes a covering index).

Note that quote.ID is not included as it is your PK (from what I can tell in the execution plan) and therefore implicitly included in the index. You can include it though - no harm done at all (e.g., index size and performance will be exactly the same).

```
CREATE INDEX IX_q ON Quotes 
    (
    LastUpdatedTicksSinceEpoch
    )
INCLUDE
    (
    PolicyId,
    [Type],
    QuoteState,
    LatestFormData,
    QuoteNumber,
    IsDiscarded
    )
WHERE 
    (
    QuoteNumber is not null 
    AND IsDiscarded = 0
    )
```

Note: I think this is probably the fastest you can get, but you need to be careful because more indexes on table mean slower inserts, updates and deletes.

Often I find a much shorter index that can be used in many places is preferable to a very specific index like this (remember, if some fields like LatestFormData are large, then this index can get bloated and not be as useful to other queries).

Comment: thanks seanb. Will this be bad if rows are updated, lets say a single quote row gets updated up to 5 times, for a span of an hour. Also, yep the LatestFormData gets large(its json valued), and it gets updated - do I just remove the LatestFormData in the index? @seanb

Comment: Note for the OP: there are two ways indexes can help. Firstly, a covering index includes all the fields you need, so they can help as you need to read less data. More importantly, an index on the correct columns allows the engine to just seek to the appropriate points. I strongly suggest Brent Ozar's [How to think like an SQL engine](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDYqU5RH_aX1VSVvjdla9TOKf939UhIDB) either 1 to 4, or #5.

Comment: One index, and one update, will rarely be a problem. It's when you have many indexes and you update thousands of row where it really starts becoming interesting (depending on hardware/memory/etc).  Re the large field: if you don't include this field in the index, then this query is no longer covered by the index, so it would need to go back to clustered index to get the data. A practical approach for this: Add the queries you need (e.g., this one) until you have too many, then optimise them.

Answer (score 3):

Create an index on:

```
create index someIndex on
Quotes (LastUpdatedTicksSinceEpoch)
include (Id, Type, LatestFormData, QuoteNumber, QuoteState, PolicyId, IsDiscarded)
where IsDiscarded = 0
```

Comment: I'm given this an uptick as you have basically the same answer (unless QuoteNumber has a lot of NULLs, which I think is unlikely) and you answered first.

Comment: I find `IS NOT NULL` filters aren’t always handled so well, so I tend to not use them as often.

Comment: For what its worth, I selected this first as my answer but when I ran it, it took forever to finish. Adding this clause(QuoteNumber is not null) actually worked for me - (ran 28 seconds). So I had to choose the seanb's answer.

Comment: Yes, there’s a big “it depends” around the selectivity and whether it’ll use the filter on null. I’m happy for Sean’s answer to be chosen.